# Certain Options Missing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuUfp.png)

Absolute beginner here, and I can't seem to access all of my options in android studio. For example, when I put in a textview in the layout, for the layout_width, fill parent option is not appearing, even though I definitely remember it to have been there when I used in briefly on my friend's computer.

Comment: `fill_parent` is not used anymore, use `match_parent` instead

Comment: Btw: only lowercase letters are allowed for image names without special characters. :)

Comment: @Prexx nice catch

Answer (score 0):

It's not there as it's not an optimal option:

> Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a
>   ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using
>   MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom
>   constraints being set to "parent".

([source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#developer-guide))

maybe you saw that option on a different layout (eg. linear).